# Convert list of strings into DateObjects

Tags: list-manipulation, date-and-time

I have a list imported from a CSV:

```
a = {{2018-07-0308-PM},{2018-07-0307-PM},{2018-07-0306-PM},{2018-07-0305-PM}}
```

and want to convert these into a DateObject[].

```
DateObject[#,{"Year","Month","Day","Hour", "AMPM"}] & /@ Map[ToString, a]
```

Which only gives:

```
{DateObject[{2018-07-0308-PM},{Year,Month,Day,Hour,AMPM}],DateObject[{2018-07-0307-PM},{Year,Month,Day,Hour,AMPM}]}
```

Any idea how to do this?

Comment: If `a` is the result of importing the list from the CSV file, what is the `Head` of each element of `a`? If it is a list of strings, then try `Map[First, a]` instead of `Map[ToString, a]`.

Answer (score 2):

```
a = {{"2018-07-0308-PM"}, {"2018-07-0307-PM"}, {"2018-07-0306-PM"}, {"2018-07-0305-PM"}}

DateObject[
 DateString[{First@#, {"Year", "-", "Month", "-", "Day", "Hour", "-", "AMPM"}}]
] & /@ a

(* {DateObject[{2018, 7, 3, 20, 0, 0.}, "Instant", "Gregorian", -5.], 
    DateObject[{2018, 7, 3, 19, 0, 0.}, "Instant", "Gregorian", -5.], 
    DateObject[{2018, 7, 3, 18, 0, 0.}, "Instant", "Gregorian", -5.], 
    DateObject[{2018, 7, 3, 17, 0, 0.}, "Instant", "Gregorian", -5.]} *)
```

Comment: Thanks. Why is it not possible to use a nested Map[...] syntax? Which I like a bit more as it's more explicit.

Comment: You can use Nested Map like: `Map[DateObject[
   DateString[{#, {"Year", "-", "Month", "-", "Day", "Hour", "-", 
      "AMPM"}}]] &, a, {2}]`

Comment: I was missing the & operator to make it a pure function. Thanks.